# Let $K$ be a collection of sets. Prove that there exists a maximal nested subcollection of $K$

Tags: general-topology

Let $K$ be a collection of sets. Prove that there exists a maximal nested subcollection of $K$.

Then $(K, \subset)$ is partially ordered, and $\emptyset\in K$, according to Hausdorff maximality principle, there exists a maximal linearly ordered subset $M$ of $S$, such that $\emptyset\subset M$.

Let $\{A_i: A_i\in K$ and $A_i\subset M\}$. I guess $\cup A_i$ is a maximal nested subcollection, but I don't know how to prove it's maximal. Actually I'm not sure whether the whole proof is in the right direction.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I haven't learned Teichmüller-Tukey lemma yet, and I don't understand why existing a maximal linearly ordered subset is equivalent existing a maximal nested subcollection?

Answer (score 0):

$K$ is a collection of sets. It is a partial order in a natural way using inclusion as $\le$.

By [Hausdorff's maximality principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_maximal_principle) it has a maximal linearly ordered subset (that contains the trivially linearly ordered $\emptyset \subseteq K$).

A nested subcollection of $K$ is just another word for a linearly ordered subfamily by inclusion so we are done. No trickery or extra proof needed (if you know the maximal principle).